# How to traverse multiple children in Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database]

I have created a Realtime database in Firebase as shown in the image, in my Android activity I need to validate that if the CUG mobile no. entered by the user matches any CUG no.(empcugno) in the database and if matched then the user is logged in.

The problems I am facing are:

1. How to traverse till every CUG no. in the database
2. Retrieve them all
3. Query each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you change your database structure a little bit by using the phone number as a unique identifier instead of that pushed id. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- Employees
          |
          ---empcugno1
          |    |
          |    --- //details
          |
          ---empcugno2
               |
               --- //details
```

To check if a number exists in the database, you can use `exists()` method directly on the `DataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference phoneNumberRef = rootRef.child("Employees").child(enteredPhoneNumber);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
phoneNumberRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, but in

DatabaseReference phoneNumberRef = rootRef.child("Employees").child(enteredPhoneNumber);

The database has different children, so different enteredPhoneNumber, will I have to make references for every enteredPhoneNumber?  
And what if my database was huge, then also different references?

Comment: Every time a user logs in, you only need to use a single reference. There is no need to traverse the enitire node. That's why I have recomended you this database structure. Ok?

Comment: By enteredPhoneNumber you meant the new keys: empcugno1,empcugno2 etc or the phone number entered by the user?

Comment: I mean the phone number enter by the user. The phone number that you want to compare with the one from your database.

Comment: Oh I confused it with the keys! I got it now, Thank you so very much! Great help!
I am also using Notification service of Firebase, in that I have coded for receiving OTP and then if it is verified then signed in and next activity starts. But the issue is if I have the app installed on my phone and I verify it once by my mobno. and then sign out, the next time I start the app it doesn't ask for OTP verification again and automatically verifies me and signs me in. I want the app to verify(by OTP) the user every time he starts the app. Can you guide me how can this be done?

Comment: You're welcome @Dpka Glad to hear that it worked. This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. In a meanwhile you can take a look at one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** where I have explained step by step, how to **[send notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&index=16&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** to specific users.

Comment: Sure! and again you were of great help, as a noob I really get confused in this! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Some more queries, 1. Can I call the code you told from line 3 till end in a button's onClickListener? 2. Can I finish this activity and start a new one in the if() statement? I actually tried to do both of these as I want this verification to happen when the user writes in the mobno and presses submit button, but it's making my app crash.

Comment: 1. You can call from the line you need it. 2. Yes  you can but it depends on how your code looks like.

Comment: String mobno = mobnoedittext.getText().toString();
private DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference PhoneNumberRef;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mob_no);
        PhoneNumberRef = rootRef.child("Employees").child(mobno);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
//Your code
             });
    }}

Comment: Try to add a fresh question. It's hard to me to understand the lines from your comment.

Comment: I have added another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314285/how-to-validate-user-with-respect-to-my-realtime-database-along-with-otp-verific

Please guide @Alex-Mamo .

Comment: I have another question but it's put on hold https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623194/no-view-found-for-fragment-in-tabllayout?noredirect=1#comment86253794_49623194 , I have provided with the whole code,I would appreciate if you go through it and let me know if I have done anything wrong, I am really stuck :/

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately I am unable to post questions, but I wanted to ask one, I want to check if the date(I have in a variable) is a Sunday or not, how can I do this? Please guide..

Comment: In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please wait until you can post another question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I know I have bothered you a lot already, but I want to know something related to this question only, if possible please guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918437/how-to-check-if-sub-child-exists-in-firebase-realtime-database/49922680#49922680