# How to validate user with respect to my Realtime Database along with OTP verification?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have created an Android app in Android Studio and linked it with Firebase Realtime database. I have used Firebase's Authentication by phone and Notification Services to send OTP to the CUG phone no. and then verify it(The code is given below).

```
public class PhoneLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneLogin";
private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
TextView t1,t2;
ImageView i1;
EditText e1,e2;
Button b1,b2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_login);

    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Phonenoedittext); //Enter Phone no.
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVerify);       //Send OTP button
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2Phone);   //Telling user to enter phone no.
    i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2Phone); //Phone icon
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OTPeditText);     //Enter OTP
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OTPVERIFY);          //Verify OTP button
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewVerified); //Telling user to enter otp
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"InValid Phone Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification code has been sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
            e1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // ...
        }
    };

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    e1.getText().toString(),
                    60,
                    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    PhoneLogin.this,
                    mCallbacks);
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, e2.getText().toString());
            // [END verify_with_code]
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }
    });


}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneLogin.this,NavigationDrawer.class));
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Invalid Verification",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Now I want to add another verification that the entered CUG no. exists in my database and then only the OTP authentication should take place. My database looks like this:

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DglmK.png)

and the code to access this database could be

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference phoneNumberRef = 
rootRef.child("Employees").child(PhoneNumberenteredByUser);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
phoneNumberRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Also, when I saw about the rules of Firebase Realtime database I noticed that it shouldn't be left public but if I need to keep it private then the user should be authenticated first, so do I need to first authenticate the user by OTP and then check if the user CUG no. exists in my database?

Edited code which is authenticating any no. even if it's not in my database:

```
public class PhoneLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "PhoneLogin";
private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
TextView t1,t2;
ImageView i1;
EditText e1,e2;
Button b1,b2;

//DBA1
private DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference phoneNumberRef;
String mobno;
//DBA1 End

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_login);

    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Phonenoedittext);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVerify);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2Phone);
    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Phone);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OTPeditText);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OTPVERIFY);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewVerified);

    mobno=e1.getText().toString();

    //DBA2
    phoneNumberRef = rootRef.child("Employees").child(mobno);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {


                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                        // Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
                        mVerificationInProgress = false;
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                        // Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // Invalid request
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"InValid Phone Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // ...
                        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                           PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                        // Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification code has been sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                        mVerificationId = verificationId;
                        mResendToken = token;
                        e1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // ...
                    }
                };

                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                                e1.getText().toString(),
                                60,
                                java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                PhoneLogin.this,
                                mCallbacks);
                    }
                });

                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, e2.getText().toString());
                        // [END verify_with_code]
                        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                    }
                });



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect CUG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    phoneNumberRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    //DBA2 End


}
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneLogin.this,NavigationDrawer.class));
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        //startActivity(new Intent(PhoneLogin.this,NavigationDrawer.class));
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Verification Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"Invalid Verification",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy,

edit your

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, e2.getText().toString());
                    // [END verify_with_code]
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                }
            });
```

with:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//Write your database reference and check in the database for entered mobno.
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child(mobno).exists()){
                        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, e2.getText().toString());
                    // [END verify_with_code]
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneLogin.this,"No such CUG No. found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps! I had such a scenario but had a workaroud to it.
First when adding data to "Employees", you can get the userId add an extra node with the userID. Lets try this

```
DatabaseReference rootRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employees");
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
rootRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(youModelClassObject);//rootRef is your database reference
```

This means on every user added to "Employees" there will be a node with their userID. Now when trying to access the database and check whether the userId which has been authenticated can be found under the employees. I would have done the following..

```
rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Object obj=ds.getKey();                     //

                Firebase user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String myId=user.getUid();

                //Specify your model class here
                ModelClass modelObject=new ModelClass();

              if(Objects.equals(myId, obj.toString())) 
                    {
                         //assuming you've set getters and setters in your model class
                         modelObject.setPhone(ds.getValue(ModelClass.class).getPhone());

                         String myDatabasePhone=modelObject.getPhone();
                         if (myDatabasePhone!=null)
                           {
                             //Now call the second OTP verification method and pass 'myDatabasePhone'
                           }                                 

                    }else {
                  //User not found
                  //direct them to a signup Activy
                    }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });`enter code here`
```

Comment: It can work, but i wanted to do it the other way round, that first it checks the database and if the no. is in my database then only it goes for OTP verification.

Comment: How do you access the database first then try and authenticate? Am sure authentication comes first which allows you to access the database

Comment: check the edit, i've added some few lines to the code

Comment: Thankyou I will look to it! 
I have asked another question, can you help me with that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356093/realtime-database-firebase-security-rules-issue

Answer (score 0):

No, by the time you are trying to authenticate the user, you need to check if the user exists. So you need to check first and then authenticate. Your code looks perfectly fine.

Regarding the rules, it's true, it shouldn't be left public. So allow only the authenticated users to make changes in your database.

Comment: but how can i merge the two codes?
and without users' authenticated id how can i make the rules private?

Comment: Inside the `onDataChange()` method, do your logic. Setting the rules to `".read": "auth != false"`, is the best choice.

Comment: It's verifying any no. with correct OTP, even though that no. is not in my database.
I cut pasted the part of authentication code in onCreate() to the ValueListener's if(datasnapshot.exists()), in onCreate() itself.

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: Any no. which has correct OTP but isn't in my database is getting verified.

Comment: No, it checks in your database that particular number. That's why you have this line of code: `rootRef.child("Employees").child(PhoneNumberenteredByUser)`.

Comment: I know.. but it's doing so, let me paste my code then you also have a look.

Comment: I have edited in my question at the end, please check.

Comment: You need to change the logic of your code. The flow should be this: On a button click, check the user for existents, if exists, log in.

Comment: I think the issue is with the security rules, can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356093/realtime-database-firebase-security-rules-issue this?

Comment: Have you tried to change the logic of your code as suggested?

Comment: What I have understood till now is, I will have to keep my database public if I need to first check for the phone no. in my database, so I will have to use cloud functions, is there anything else which can be done for this?

Comment: This is also an option, you can give it a try. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: But I don't want to keep my  database public, and, understanding and using cloud functions is difficult for me as per now; isn't there any other way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Is up to you what you choose to solve this but I already provide you my options. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!