# How to check if sub child exists in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My main node Employees has 3 values: Mob. no., UserPIN and empID. I need to check in one of my activities that if the entered UserPIN exists under thos node or not. I am not able to do this by using:

```
if(datasnapshot.child(enteredUserPIN).exists(){
}
```

And also I can't change my node layout as I am checking for the Mob. no. as well in another activity. Plus I can't directly give the path till the Mob. no.
Please guide.

Employees node:

[image: Employees table]

**EDIT**

My code:

```
private void mpinexists(){
    Log.d("abcd","mpinexists() reached");
    checkmPINRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(ds.child(enteredmPIN).exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"mPIN already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("abcd","mpin already exists");

                }
                else{
                    Log.d("abcd","mpin doesn't exists");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"mPIN doesn't exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
}
```

My Log:

```
04-25 21:53:28.889 10147-10147/com.example.abcd.efg D/abcd: mpinexists() reached
04-25 21:53:31.471 10147-10147/com.example.abcd.efg D/abcd: mpin already exists
04-25 21:53:31.472 10147-10147/com.example.abcd.efg D/abcd: mpin doesn't exists
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo No... I have for the time being created another key in the table as UserPIN and stored the UserPIN again, is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, it is. So it will be helpful fir you if I'll write you another solution?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, you need to use a `Query` and `exists()` method on the `DataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef
    .child("Employees")
    .child(mobileNumber) //Could be: 765432189
    .child(userPin) //Could be: 123457
    .orderBychild("empid")
    .equalsTo(enteredUserPIN);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            //Do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

According to your edit, please use the follwing code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference employeesRef = rootRef.child("Employees");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(ds.child(enteredUserPIN).exists()) {
                //Do something
            } else {
                //Do something else
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
employeesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: oh okay but I need to check the UserPIN without the knowledge of mobileNumber. It's like I just want to traverse the whole table and see if any data matches.

Comment: Ok, you don't know the mobile number but do you know the `userPin`? Let's say `123457`?

Comment: Yes, I need to see if a given userPin exists or not

Comment: There is something that I don't understand. You need to check if the value of `empid` is equal to `enteredUserPIN` or you want to check if `userPin`, which can be `123457` exists?

Comment: The second one, I need to check that when the user enters a UserPin, then does it exists in the table or not

Comment: It didn't work, I just put Toasts and it returned UserPin doesn't exists. :/

Comment: It's doing something odd, it's going into both, if and else, I am editing in my question

Comment: It's normal to do that. Is there also a message that says it exist?

Comment: That's correct. This is happening because for every iteration of your loop you take a action. If you need to do something only if the user pin exists then just remove the else part of your statement. Otherwise, you need to do a separate node, in which you need to store only user pins. In that situation you don't need to loop over the children, but with this database structure there is no alternative. Is it now clear?

Comment: Oh okay, thankyou so much! :) hey one more thing, will this code work no matter how many sub-keys my table has?

Comment: I would like to know the reason behind that if I have put 'if-else' in my for loop then why does it go to 'else' if my 'if' condition was true? Logically it shouldn't happen so, 'if-else' is for this motive only.

Comment: For each iteration, the if statement is triggered. So if you have 10 items, 10 times the if statement is triggered. Which means that for those 10 times that is called, either true or false will be will be printed. If the pin exists, `true` it will be printed once and `false` the other 9 times. That's why I said, if you want to have a different behaviour, you need to do a separate node, in which you need to store only user pins.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the current table layout. You should create a separate node where you just put all the pins as key value pair e.g Pin as Key and true as value. You can check there if the pin exists or not

Comment: No other way? :/

Comment: Well, this is the most straightforward approach and this is what people do in general.  So, in this way, your response will be much faster as you can directly access the child once you know the pin and check for existence without accessing any unnecessary check.

Comment: That's fine but I would like to know for my knowledge, if there is any way to check a sub child in the way I want to?

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hasChildren ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getDesigns();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```